# Combine Two SQL queries into one single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with structure

```
TicketID - ID of the Ticket
CreateTime - Time when the ticket is created
FinishTime - Time when the ticket is finished handled
```

My objective is to find these values based on hour

```
Number of Tickets Received per hour
Number of Tickets handled per hour
```

So far I have come with 2 separate queries

```
Select count(Receipt.ID) as ReceiveCount,
       Receipt.hours as PST,
      (Receipt.hours+12.5) as IST 
from
      (Select ReceiptScanRequestTable.ReceiptScanRequestID as ID,
              from_unixtime(CreateTime/1000 , '%H') as hours 
       from 
              ReceiptScanRequestTable 
       where 
              CreateTime>{hour_filter_value}  
      ) as Receipt 
Group By 
      Receipt.hours
```

This will return Number of tickets received per hour

```
Select count(Receipt.ID) as FinishCount,
           Receipt.hours as PST,
          (Receipt.hours+12.5) as IST 
    from
          (Select ReceiptScanRequestTable.ReceiptScanRequestID as ID,
                  from_unixtime(FinisheTime/1000 , '%H') as hours 
           from 
                  ReceiptScanRequestTable 
           where 
                  CreateTime>{hour_filter_value}  
          ) as Receipt 
    Group By 
          Receipt.hours
```

This will return Number of tickets finished per hour

My objective is to combine the two queries into a single one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` and then aggregate:

```
select hours, sum(receive) as numreceived, sum(finish) as numfinished,
       (hours + 12.5) as IST 
from ((Select from_unixtime(CreateTime/1000 , '%H') as hours, 1 as receive, 0 as finish
       from ReceiptScanRequestTable 
       where CreateTime > {hour_filter_value}
      ) union all
      (Select from_unixtime(FinisheTime/1000 , '%H') as hours, 0, 1
       from ReceiptScanRequestTable 
       where CreateTime>{hour_filter_value}  
      )
     ) r
group by hours;
```

Comment: Could you please explain what those 0 and 1 does?I can't seem to get my head around that!

Comment: @SamJawahar he is "flagging" the results from the first query in the union as "receives", and the second parts' as "finishes". UNIONs require all queries involved to have the same number and type of columns. `, 0, 1` is basically `, 0 AS receive, 1 as finish`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select receivecount, finishcount from (Select count(Receipt.ID) as ReceiveCount,
       Receipt.hours as PST,
      (Receipt.hours+12.5) as IST 
from
      (Select ReceiptScanRequestTable.ReceiptScanRequestID as ID,
              from_unixtime(CreateTime/1000 , '%H') as hours 
       from 
              ReceiptScanRequestTable 
       where 
              CreateTime>{hour_filter_value}  
      ) as Receipt 
Group By 
      Receipt.hours) a 
cross apply
(Select count(Receipt.ID) as FinishCount,
           Receipt.hours as PST,
          (Receipt.hours+12.5) as IST 
    from
          (Select ReceiptScanRequestTable.ReceiptScanRequestID as ID,
                  from_unixtime(FinisheTime/1000 , '%H') as hours 
           from 
                  ReceiptScanRequestTable 
           where 
                  CreateTime>{hour_filter_value}  
          ) as Receipt 
    Group By 
          Receipt.hours)b
```

Comment: I don't believe that MySQL supports `cross apply`.